# Filter an array by part of data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to make a country and town related select

The country data is

```
var arr_country=[
  {"id": 100,"name":"台北市"},
  {"id": 200,"name":"新北市"},
  {"id": 300,"name":"桃園市"},
  {"id": 400,"name":"新竹縣"},
  {"id": 500,"name":"台中市"}
  ]

var arr_town=[
  {"id": 10011,"name":"中正區"},
  {"id": 10022,"name":"信義區"},
  {"id": 20011,"name":"板橋區"},
  {"id": 20022,"name":"永和區"},
  {"id": 30011,"name":"龜山區"},
  {"id": 30022,"name":"八德區"},
  {"id": 40011,"name":"新豐鄉"},
  {"id": 40022,"name":"湖口區"},
  {"id": 50011,"name":"北屯區"},
  {"id": 50022,"name":"大雅區"}
]
```

and the HTML code is

```
<select id="country"></select>
<select id="town"></select>
```

I can't change the JSON data format

and these two data's relation is

country id = XXX

town id = XXXOO

how can I filter the match array to dynamic insert options to town select

I try to write some script

```
var counties_option = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr_country.length; i++) {
counties_option += '<option value="' + arr_country[i].id + '">' + arr_country[i].name + '</option>';
}

$('#country')
.append(counties_option)
.on('change',function(){
$('#town').empty();

var selected_counties=this.value
var filtered_arr=arr_town.filter(function(item){
return item.id==selected_counties;
});

var town_option = '';
for (var j = 0; j < filtered_arr.length; j++) {
town_option += '<option value="' + filtered_arr[j].id + '">' + filtered_arr[j].name + '</option>';
}

$('#town').append(town_option)}).trigger('change');
```

this is my jsFiddle practice => [jsFiddle practice](http://jsfiddle.net/baibai/x1qh4b0t/16/)

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please EDIT your question to show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your function like this

```
var filtered_arr=arr_town.filter(function(item){
    return item.id.toString().substring(0,3)==selected_counties;         
  });
```

This is working, I have updated your jsfiddle as well.http://jsfiddle.net/nmongiya/0dj6uaph/

Answer (score 1):

In the attempt that you posted, the problem seems to be with the way you're generating `filtered_arr`. To get the towns for a given country, you may want to try something like the following:

```js
function getTowns(country) {
  return arr_town.filter(function(town) {
    return Math.floor(town.id / 100) === country.id;
  });
}

var arr_country=[
  {"id": 100,"name":"台北市"},
  {"id": 200,"name":"新北市"},
  {"id": 300,"name":"桃園市"},
  {"id": 400,"name":"新竹縣"},
  {"id": 500,"name":"台中市"}
];

var arr_town=[
  {"id": 10011,"name":"中正區"},
  {"id": 10022,"name":"信義區"},
  {"id": 20011,"name":"板橋區"},
  {"id": 20022,"name":"永和區"},
  {"id": 30011,"name":"龜山區"},
  {"id": 30022,"name":"八德區"},
  {"id": 40011,"name":"新豐鄉"},
  {"id": 40022,"name":"湖口區"},
  {"id": 50011,"name":"北屯區"},
  {"id": 50022,"name":"大雅區"}
];

console.log(getTowns(arr_country[0]));
console.log(getTowns(arr_country[1]));
console.log(getTowns(arr_country[2]));
```

Comment: Better use `Math.floor` instead of `parseInt`. parseInt is for parsing strings.

Comment: Actually, the country id and the town id will not be 100/200/300, by government data, the id will be 10008/10009/64000...etc, so, I think using parseInt or Math.floor method is not a good resolve way...

Comment: @PaiYaWen what is `Math.floor(10008 / 100)`?